# NHibernate - logging

Tags: nhibernate

I'm using log4net with NHibernate and i'm logging SQL statements generated by NHibernate.

Is there any way to instruct NHibernate to only log DML SQL statements (inserts, updates, deletes), for example something like "NHibernate.SQL" + ".DML" in log configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add another logger node to your configuration file for NHibernate.DML  That will log both.

Answer (score 0):

No. Unfortunately there is no built in way for what you want.